# Shipping SDL2 C Project in Ubuntu

Tags: c, sdl, project-management

everyone! I have created a SDL2 project in Ubuntu using C and the terminal as compiler.
I want to ship the project in order to send it to my friends.
Does anybody know how to achieve that without needing to install the library on the very computer it arrives?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited for StackOverflow since it pertains to software development and doesn't have very much to do with Ubuntu.  In any case, you are probably going to have to share a lot more information about your project.

Comment: Ok. I'll post that also on StackOverflow. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you asking how to *package* and how to *distribute* software?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, sorry if I wasn't specific enough. I didn't want to lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: How to package software as a deb: http://mentors.debian.net. How to package software as a Snap: http://snapcraft.io. The package system you choose determines the distribution method (Ubuntu repos, PPA, Snap Store, etc) choices that you can use.